# How to add a new object to an already created list?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I'm trying to add a new object to a list that already starts 5 on the click of a button, but I'm having trouble accomplishing this in Android studio. This is my code to populate the list with the original 5.

```
private ArrayList<Course> populateList() {

    ArrayList<Course> list = new ArrayList<>();


    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Course course = new Course();
        list.add(course);
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: At what point do you wish to add another object? If you want to add it within the populateList() function, then list.add(course) should do it. However, if you wish to add outside of the function, make your ArrayList global and add it where ever you want to.

Comment: What you have will generate your original list of 5 courses and return the list. What exactly are you having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to add any item just write

```
listName.add(object);
```

but if you speak about listview or any recycler you should notify every change 
by

```
Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to do this once again per button click.

```
Course course = new Course();
list.add(course);
```

If you're showing the list in a RecyclerView or ListView, you need to call `notifyDatasetChanged` in order for the view to refresh the list and show the new item.

Answer (score 0):

```
        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Course course = new Course();
            list.add(course);
            courseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```